# How to fix use of moved value in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert a yaml file to xml using Rust and I am not able to figure out how to fix this error regarding the use of moved value. I think I understand why this error is coming, but haven't got a clue about what to do next.

Here's the code:

```
struct Element {
    element_name: String,
    indentation_count: i16,
}

struct Attribute<'a> {
    attribute_name: &'a str,
    attribute_value: &'a str,
}

fn convert_yaml_to_xml(content: String, indentation_count: i16) -> String {
    let mut xml_elements: Vec<Element> = vec![];
    let mut attributes: Vec<Attribute> = vec![];
    xml_elements.push(Element {element_name: "xmlRoot".to_string(), indentation_count: -1});
    let mut target: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let mut xml_data_writer = EmitterConfig::new().perform_indent(true).create_writer(&mut target);

    let mut attribute_written_flag = false;
    let mut xml_event;
    xml_event = XmlEvent::start_element("xmlRoot");
    for line in content.lines() {
        let current_line = line.trim();
        let caps = indentation_count_regex.captures(current_line).unwrap();
        let current_indentation_count = caps.get(1).unwrap().as_str().to_string().len() as i16;
        if ELEMENT_REGEX.is_match(current_line) {
            loop {
                let current_attribute_option = attributes.pop();
                match current_attribute_option {
                    Some(current_attribute_option) => {
                        xml_event.attr(current_attribute_option.attribute_name, current_attribute_option.attribute_value)
                    },
                    None => {
                        break;
                    },
                };
            }
            xml_data_writer.write(xml_event);
            // Checking if the line is an element
            let caps = ELEMENT_REGEX.captures(current_line).unwrap();
            let element_name = caps.get(2);
            let xml_element_struct = Element {
                indentation_count: current_indentation_count,
                element_name: element_name.unwrap().as_str().to_string(),
            };
            xml_elements.push(xml_element_struct);
            xml_event = XmlEvent::start_element(element_name.unwrap().as_str());
            attribute_written_flag = false;
        } else if ATTR_REGEX.is_match(current_line) {
            // Checking if the line is an attribute
            let caps = ATTR_REGEX.captures(current_line).unwrap();
            let attr_name = caps.get(2);
            let attr_value = caps.get(3);
            // Saving attributes to a stack
            attributes.push(Attribute{ attribute_name: attr_name.unwrap().as_str(), attribute_value: attr_value.unwrap().as_str() });
            // xml_event.attr(attr_name.unwrap().as_str(), attr_value.unwrap().as_str());
        }/* else if NEW_ATTR_SET_REGEX.is_match(current_line) {
        let caps = NEW_ATTR_SET_REGEX.captures(current_line).unwrap();
        let new_attr_set_name = caps.get(2);
        let new_attr_set_value = caps.get(3);
        current_xml_hash.insert("name".to_string(), new_attr_set_name.unwrap().as_str().to_string());
        current_xml_hash.insert("value".to_string(), new_attr_set_value.unwrap().as_str().to_string());
    } */
    }
    if attribute_written_flag {
        xml_data_writer.write(xml_event);
    }
    for item in xml_elements.iter() {
        let event = XmlEvent::end_element();
        let event_name = item.element_name.to_string();
        xml_data_writer.write(event.name(event_name.as_str()));
    }
    println!("OUTPUT");
    println!("{:?}", target);
    return "".to_string();
}
```

And here's the error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `xml_event`
   --> src/main.rs:77:25
    |
65  |     let mut xml_event;
    |         ------------- move occurs because `xml_event` has type `StartElementBuilder<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
77  |                         xml_event.attr(current_attribute_option.attribute_name, current_attribute_option.attribute_value)
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `xml_event` moved due to this method call, in previous iteration of loop
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `xml_event`
   --> /Users/defiant/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/xml-rs-0.8.4/src/writer/events.rs:193:24
    |
193 |     pub fn attr<N>(mut self, name: N, value: &'a str) -> StartElementBuilder<'a>
    |                        ^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`XmlEvent::start_element()` documentation](https://netvl.github.io/xml-rs/xml/writer/events/enum.XmlEvent.html#method.start_element) we see that it produces a `StartElementBuilder<'a>`.

From [`StartElementBuilder<'a>::attr()` documentation](https://netvl.github.io/xml-rs/xml/writer/events/struct.StartElementBuilder.html#method.attr) we see that it **consumes** the `StartElementBuilder<'a>` (the first parameter is `self`, not `&mut self`) and produces a new `StartElementBuilder<'a>` (which is probably similar to `self` but considers the expected effect of `.attr()`).

This approach is known as the [**consuming** builder pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/ownership/builders.html#consuming-builders:), which is used in Rust (for example [`std::thread::Builder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html)).

The typical usage of such an approach consists in chaining the function calls: `something.a().b().c().d()` such as `something` is **consumed** by `a()`, its result is **consumed** by `b()`, the same about `c()` and finally `d()` does something useful with the last result.
The alternative would be to use mutable borrows in order to modify *in place* `something` but dealing with mutable borrows is known as difficult in some situations.

In your case, you can just reassign the result of `.attr()` to `xml_event` because otherwise the `.attr()` function would have no effect (its result is discarded) and `xml_event` would become unusable because it is consumed; reassigning it makes it usable again afterwards (at least i guess, i didn't try).